# Is there a french version for this paper "Critical exponents of Fujita type for certain evolution equations .."?

Tags: reference-request, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I seek many times in the web to get the French version of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X0500260X)  entitled " Critical exponents of Fujita type for certain evolution equations and systems
with spatio-temporal fractional derivatives " But i didn't find it , any references ? And what are the application of Fijita type in Physics ?

Comment: What is the "French version"? Do you mean a translation into French?

Comment: yes this what i meant